# How to "join" four smaller matrix together to form a bigger matrix?

Tags: c#, arrays, join, matrix, int

In c# I've got four 10x10 int square matrices and I need to create a 20x20 square matrix by merging the four smaller matrices.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

EDIT: This is my code

```
                int[] first = myArray.Take(myArray.Length / 2).ToArray();
            int[] second = myArray.Skip(myArray.Length / 2).ToArray();

            int[,] matrice0 = MatrixCalc(first, first);
            int[,] matrice1 = MatrixCalc(first, second);
            int[,] matrice2 = MatrixCalc(second, first);
            int[,] matrice3 = MatrixCalc(second, second);
            // Need to join these four matrices here like this: [[0 1][2 3]]
```

Comment: join them how? `[[0 1][2 3]]` or `[[0 2][1 3]]`?

Comment: @JuliánUrbano `[[0 1][2 3]]`

Comment: Have you got any specific problem with at least some way that you tried yourself?

Comment: I've tried a bit with `Array.copy` but i'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: Any chance you could post your attempt? `Array.Copy` seems like the best choice here in terms of performance and still maintainable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickly put together a simple non-scalable solution (only for 4 matrices, if you need a scalable solution you can look at having the matrix as a list of lists and concatenate them) that supposes the matrix lenght is the same. Haven't compiled it so sorry for any bugs

```
int[,] joinedMatrice = new int[matrice0.GetLength(0) + matrice1.GetLength(0), matrice0.GetLength(1) + matrice2.GetLength(1)];

    for (int i = 0; i < matrice0.GetLength(0) + matrice1.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrice0.GetLength(1) + matrice2.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            int value = 0;
            if (i < matrice0.GetLength(0) && j < matrice0.GetLength(1))
            {
                value = matrice0[i, j];
            }
            else if (i >= matrice0.GetLength(0) && j < matrice0.GetLength(1))
            {
                value = matrice1[i - matrice0.GetLength(0), j];
            }
            else if (i < matrice0.GetLength(0) && j >= matrice0.GetLength(1))
            {
                value = matrice2[i, j - matrice0.GetLength(1)];
            }
            else if (i >= matrice0.GetLength(0) && j >= matrice0.GetLength(1))
            {
                value = matrice3[i - matrice0.GetLength(0), j - matrice0.GetLength(1)];
            }

            joinedMatrice[i, j] = value;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
// pre-arrange them in the form you want
List<List<int[,]>> sources = new List<List<int[,]>>() {
    new List<int[,]>() {matrice0, matrice1},
    new List<int[,]>() {matrice2, matrice3}
};

int[,] joint = new int[20, 20];
for (int i = 0; i < joint.GetLength(0); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < joint.GetLength(1); j++) {
        // select the matrix corresponding to value (i,j)
        int[,] source = sources[i / matrice0.GetLength(0)][j / matrice0.GetLength(1)];
        // and copy the value
        joint[i, j] = source[i % matrice0.GetLength(0), j % matrice0.GetLength(1)];
    }
}
```